# cocos-2d collision detection with a rect and falling objects

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

I've got a player sprite that I can move around on the screen using the accelerometer. Now I want to check if it collides with any of the **many** randomly falling objects I've created. I know about the `CGRectIntersectsRect` function, but I don't want to have to know the other object's name. Is there some kind of getElementAt function like in Java, that I can continue to check if there is **any** object overlapping with my player?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only cocos2d equivalent to `getElementAt` I know of is `getChildByTag:`. Alternatively You can loop through every child of the layer using:

```
for (CCNode *child in [self children]) {
    if (CGRectIntersects(child.boundingBox, player.boundingBox) {
        // perform collision stuff    
    }
}
```

Also important to remember is that this is horribly inefficient, particularly with **many** objects. You might consider using a physics engine to perform the efficient collision detection for you.